# How to build custom breadcrumbs

Tags: 7, breadcrumbs

I have to build a breadcrumbs, In fack I only need to add a breacrumbs between the "home" and the "books breadcrumbs" to get something like this:

> home>>view-path>>book-breadcrumbs-with-deep

I have try with paths breadcrumbs, with hansel, and with custom breadcrumbs, I don't get nothing.

There is another module, or I should make my own module?

Thanks

Oskar

Comment: Seems that http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_menu_breadcrumb_alter/7 is the best option.

Comment: That's the hook. I can post an example in the morning.

Comment: Thaks MPD, I finished the code this morning.

Answer (score 1):

You can accomplish this with [`hook_menu_breadcrumb_alter()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_menu_breadcrumb_alter/7):

```
function mymodule_menu_breadcrumb_alter(&$active_trail, $item) {
  $home = $active_trail[0];

  $new = array(
    'title' => t('Some title'),
    'href' => 'internal/drupal/path',
    'link_path' => '',
    'localized_options' => array(),
    'type' => 0,
  );

  $active_trail = array_merge(array($home, $new), array_slice($active_trail, 1));
}
```

This is a fairly simplified example that creates a new breadcrumb item, and sticks it after the first entry.  The `$item` parameter will be the router entry for the current page.  If you want to use that, you need to `dpm()` it to see what is there.  A more concrete example, which assumes that you are on a node page would be:

```
function mymodule_menu_breadcrumb_alter(&$active_trail, $item) {
  $home = $active_trail[0];

  if (arg(0) == 'search') {
    $active_trail = array($home);
  }
  else if (isset($item['load_functions'][1]) && !empty($item['map'][1]) && $item['load_functions'][1] == 'node_load') {
    $node = $item['map'][1];

    $new = array(
      'title' => $node->title,
      'href' => 'node/' . $node->nid,
      'link_path' => '',
      'localized_options' => array(),
      'type' => 0,
    );

    $active_trail = array_merge(array($home, $new), array_slice($active_trail, 1));
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Check out [Crumbs](https://www.drupal.org/project/crumbs) module as well, it provides a plugin system so you can customize them to a high level.

There's an [Example plugin](https://www.drupal.org/node/1398876) in the documentation.

```
/**
 * Implements hook_crumbs_plugins()
 */
function mycrumbs_crumbs_plugins($api) {
  $api->monoPlugin('default');
}
class mycrumbs_CrumbsMonoPlugin_default implements crumbs_MonoPlugin {
  function describe($api) {
    $api->setTitle('Frontpage and classic theme area');
  }
  /**
   * Find a parent path, if the router path is node/%.
   *
   * @param $path
   *   The system path that we want to find a parent for.
   * @param $item
   *   The router item, as returned by menu_get_item(),
   *   with a few convenience additions.
   * @return
   *   System path or alias for the parent path.
   */
  function findParent__node_x($path, $item) {
    $node = $item['map'][1];
    $lang = $GLOBALS['language']->language;
    // This site has Organic Groups (Drupal 6) installed.
    if (!empty($node->og_groups)) {
      // Pick the first group nid.
      foreach ($node->og_groups as $gid) {
        if ($group = node_load($gid)) break;
      }
      // We have a node type "city_group" set up as an OG group type.
      if ($group && $group->type == 'city_group') {
        switch ($node->type) {
          case 'event':
          case 'group_event':
            return "node/$gid/events";
          case 'group_discussion':
            return "node/$gid/news";
        }
      }
    }
    // Some rules for other node types, which are not group posts.
    switch ($node->type) {
      case 'news':
        return 'news';
      case 'simplenews':
        return 'news-media/newsletters';
      case 'video':
        return 'news-media/video';
      case 'photo':
        return 'news-media/photo-library';
      case 'city_group':
        return 'city-groups/list';
    }
    // Use the generic findParent() method as a fallback.
    return $this->findParent($path, $item);
  }
  /**
   * Find a parent path, for arbitrary router paths.
   *
   * @param $path
   *   The system path that we want to find a parent for.
   * @param $item
   *   The router item, as returned by menu_get_item(),
   *   with a few convenience additions.
   */
  function findParent($path, $item) {
    switch ($item['alias']) {
      case 'news':
        return 'news-media';
      case 'og':
      case 'city-groups':
        // This will make a breadcrumb of
        // Home > Community > City groups > ...
        return 'community';
    }
  }
  /**
   * Determine a breadcrumb item's title, for a router path of "node".
   * Actually, we totally skip 'node'.
   *
   * @param $path
   *   The system path that we want to find a parent for.
   * @param $item
   *   The router item, as returned by menu_get_item(),
   *   with a few convenience additions.
   * @return
   *   A string to be used as the title, OR
   *   FALSE, to totally skip this item.
   */
  function findTitle__node($path, $item) {
    // Always skip 'node'
    // For instance, for node/123 "Some page", we don't want a breadcrumb of
    // Home > Node > Some page, but rather
    // Home > Some page
    return FALSE;
  }
  /**
   * The breadcrumb is finished, and we get a chance to alter it.
   *
   * We could use this method to skip or abbreviate some items, if the
   * breadcrumb gets too long.
   */
  function decorateBreadcrumb(&$breadcrumb) {
    // Do nothing.
  }
}
```

Comment: These plugins have nothing to do with ctools :) just fyi.

Comment: and in this case you get along without a plugin..

Comment: I always thought it was ctool based :) thanks for the heads up. Any reason not to? In any case feel free to fix my answer :) I've removed the ctools part

Comment: I posted my own answer below..

Comment: The reason I don't use ctools: 1. Hierarchical prioritization. 2. The part of Crumbs that would become smaller with ctools is rather small already. Most of the heavy stuff is special logic where ctools won't help. 3. I don't know too much of ctools. 4. ctools architecture looks quite old-school -ish to me. (pick any number of these)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do this with Crumbs (7.x-2.*):

Useful things to know:

- Book structures are menus.
- Book pages are nodes, usually (or always?) the bundle is "Book page".

Steps:

1. Install Crumbs.
2. Visit `admin/structure/crumbs/entity-parent`.

   1. Set the path of the views page as the parent path for "Book page".
3. Visit `admin/structure/crumbs` (the weights configuration).

   1. Make sure that `menu.hierarchy.MENU_NAME` and `menu.link_title.MENU_NAME` are enabled. MENU_NAME should be the menu that contains the book hierarchy. Or just use the `menu.hierarchy.*` and `menu.link_title.*` wildcard plugins to have all menus enabled.
   2. Make sure that `crumbs.entityParent.node.book` (or a respective wildcard) is enabled. Hint: It probably already is enabled, without you doing anything!
   3. Make sure that the priority of `menu.link_title.MENU_NAME` comes before that of `crumbs.entityParent.node.book`. This is super important, because otherwise the entityParent plugin will dominate and steal the show.
4. Make sure that Crumbs can find a breadcrumb title for the views page. Usually Crumbs looks into the menu_router table for a title or title callback, but Views often needs some extra babysitting. An easy solution is to create a regular menu link for the Views page, in whichever menu you prefer.
5. Visit `admin/structure/crumbs/debug` for troubleshooting. If you see the breadcrumb item crossed out, it means Crumbs was not able to find a title for that item.

Answer (score 0):

Check [Path Breadcrums](https://www.drupal.org/project/path_breadcrumbs) - I find it easiest and most useful for your task.

And here's some other breadcrumb modules comparison:
https://www.drupal.org/node/533448

Answer (score -1):

My favorite method is to use the Custom Breadcrumbs module is for me the only one that takes into account all possibilities and is capable of generating a real Breadcrumb. I have a post explciando obtaining a real Breadcrumb for example if a node has multiple paths to reach it.
[Get a real breadcrumb, Drupal](http://drupaltokens.com/blog/get-real-breadcrumb-custom-breadcrumbs-module-your-drupal-site)

Good luck!

Comment: Whilst this link may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link only for reference. If link is posted for any other reason than answering or referencing answer, it shouldn't be posted in answer at all. With a bit more rep, [you will be able to post comments](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/privileges/comment).